# Crystal Report 2008 - How to Sum a Value in Header section?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a master-detail tables, I need to sum a value in master table only but the sum appear duplicated by the numbers of rows in the detail table !!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you placed the summary/formula field within the `Details` section.

If the summary field is a *group summary*, move it to either the `Group Header` or `Group Footer` sections. If the summary field is a *report summary*, move it to either the `Report Header` or `Report Footer` sections.